# Whats wrong with this piece of code?

Tags: javascript

Trying to figure out what's wrong with this piece of code.

```
 //Code to return the sum of all values in an array
 var x = [ 1,2,3,4,5 ]; 

 //Function to return sum of values in an array
 function sum(arr) {

   var sum = 0;

   for (i=1; i < arr.length; i++) {
     sum = sum + x[i];
   }

   return sum;
 }
```

What will be the value of `sum(x)`?

Comment: `i` must start at index 0

Comment: You probably intended to add arr[i] rather than x[i] if you want sum() to work for more than one array.

Comment: Note the ES6 syntax (when you're ready for it) works well too: `let sum = x.reduce((p, c) => p + c);`

Comment: Just for fun: `sum=arr=>eval(arr.join('+'));`

Comment: Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should @user6188402 :)

Comment: Im still learning to love ES6....its a little cryptic for me still...Im fine with the lamda, its the lack of the word function for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple issues here, some are worse than others

First of all you should delcare i as a variable, `i=0` -> `var i = 0`

Then you need to start your for loop at 0 instead of 1 `for(var i = 1` -> `for(var i = 0` Arrays in javascript (and pretty much every other language) are 0-indexed. That means the first item is `arrayName[0]` not `arrayName[1]`

Then you were accessing your value in the array wrong you need to use `arr[i]` not `x[i]`. You want to access the value passed to the function, not the actual array you created before.

Line 8 can be shortened using `+=` and was also missing a semicolon

```
//Code to return the sum of all values in an array
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

//Function to return sum of values in an array
function sum(arr) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
console.log(sum(x)); //15 -- it works! (1+2+3+4+5=15)
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated the issue is that arrays, and most other things in programming, are zero-indexed.

May I suggest an alternative stylistic choice...

```
 var x = [ 1,2,3,4,5 ]; 

 //Function to return sum of values in an array
 var sum = function (arr) {
   return arr.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b;})
 }

 console.log(sum(x));
```

Though, at this point the function is one line of code, and not really worth wrapping in a function. With things like that I simply do it inline.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: return the result of a `reduce` is simpler.

Comment: your right, I was thinking forEach was older and that reduce was not as compatible with IE. But both require IE9, so may as well use the more appropriate function. Ive updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @user6188402 mentions, `i` must start at 0.

Here's why:

`var x = [ 1,2,3,4,5 ];` creates an array whose index starts at 0, so:

```
x[0] = 1
x[1] = 2
x[2] = 3
x[3] = 4
x[4] = 5
```

If you do `sum = sum + x[i];` starting at 1, the answer will be `14` instead of `15`